# socat: "E connect(5, LEN=4 AF=1 ":0", 4): No such file or directory" when trying to run GUI application in docker on Mac OS

Tags: macos, ubuntu, docker, xorg

I'm trying to run a GUI application inside an Ubuntu Docker container on a Mac host machine.

My testing Dockerfile, tagged `xterm`, is

```
FROM ubuntu:xenial

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y xterm
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash xterm
USER xterm
WORKDIR /home/xterm
```

Following [this tutorial](https://kartoza.com/en/blog/how-to-run-a-linux-gui-application-on-osx-using-docker/), I

- allowed connections from network clients in XQuartz
- started `socat TCP-LISTEN:6000,reuseaddr,fork UNIX-CLIENT:\"$DISPLAY\"`, which printed `E connect(5, LEN=4 AF=1 ":0", 4): No such file or directory`.
- Opened XQuartz
- ran `docker run -it --rm -e DISPLAY=192.168.178.36:0 --entrypoint /usr/bin/xterm xterm`, where `192.168.178.36` is the en0 IP address. This outputs `/usr/bin/xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: 192.168.178.36:0` and the error appears a second time in socat. No GUI is shown.

What does the `socat` error mean?

System details:

- Docker Desktop 2.2.1.0, with Docker Engine 19.03.05
- MacOS Mojave version 10.14.5

Answer (score 2):

It seems the XQuartz X Socket is named `/tmp/.X11-unix/X0`, at least that file gets created by XQuartz when XQuartz launches, but the `DISPLAY` variable contained ":0", so `socat` was forwarding to a non-existing socket.

When I use that file instead of ":0" in the socat command (`socat TCP-LISTEN:6000,reuseaddr,fork UNIX-CLIENT:/tmp/.X11-unix/X0`), I get no error anymore. Running the xterm container additionally prints `No protocol specified` before the `Can't open display` error.

That is resolved by authenticating, I ran `xhost +` which finally allowed running `xterm`, but that is insecure and it might be better to do it [with xauth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51795708/1726797).